# $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$, such that $a+b+c = 3$. Prove that $\frac{a^2}{b+c} + \frac{b^2}{c+a} + \frac{c^2}{a+b} \ge \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$, such that $a+b+c = 3$. Prove that $\frac{a^2}{b+c} + \frac{b^2}{c+a} + \frac{c^2}{a+b} \ge \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}$ .

**`My Attempt:`**

By applying rearrangement twice and adding ,
$$2(\frac{a^2}{b+c} + \frac{b^2}{c+a} + \frac{c^2}{a+b}) \ge \frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c} + \frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a} + \frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b}$$

So the inequality now becomes,
$$\frac{b^2+c^2}{b+c} + \frac{c^2+a^2}{c+a} + \frac{a^2+b^2}{a+b} \ge a^2+b^2+c^2$$

which changes into
$$\frac{2bc}{b+c} + \frac{2ca}{c+a} + \frac{2ab}{a+b} \ge a^2+b^2+c^2$$

*How to proceed from here ?*

Or any elegant and good approach/idea using **rearrangement** or **chebyshev** !

Comment: Again, have you seen [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1700970p10926624)? There is a link to a complete solution [here](https://mathifc.wordpress.com/2011/10/21/inequality-87/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way.
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{3-a}-\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a-1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-1)^2(2a+3)}{3-a}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^4}{a^2b+a^2c}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)}$$ and it remains to prove that:
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b+c)\geq3\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2(a+b+c)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{3a^2}{2(a+b+c)}\right)=\frac{1}{2(a+b+c)}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(2a-b-c)}{b+c}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2(a+b+c)}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(a-b-(c-a))}{b+c}=\frac{1}{2(a+b+c)}\sum_{cyc}(a-b)\left(\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{b^2}{a+c}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2(a+b+c)}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a-b)^2(a^2+b^2+ab+ac+bc)}{(a+c)(b+c)}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 2):

Another way.

We need to prove that:
$$2(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}a^2(a+b)(a+c)\geq3(a^2+b^2+c^2)\prod_{cyc}(a+b)$$ or
$$2\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}(a^4+a^3b+a^3c+a^2bc)\geq\sum_{cyc}a^2\sum_{cyc}(3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)$$ or
$$\sum_{sym}(a^5+a^4b-a^3b^2-a^2b^2c)\geq0,$$ which is true by Muirhead.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

Since triples $$\left(\frac{a^2}{b+c},\frac{b^2}{a+c},\frac{c^2}{a+b}\right)$$ and  $$(2a-b-c,2b-a-c,2c-a-b)$$ have the same ordering, by Chebyshov we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{2(a+b+c)}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{b+c}-\frac{3a^2}{2(a+b+c)}\right)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(2a-b-c)}{b+c}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{18}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b+c}\sum_{cyc}(2a-b-c)=0$$